# Reading from RichTextBox in VC++

Tags: visual-c++, richtextbox, user-input

I have to read the text character by character from a `RichTextBox` in VC++. I need a function like `getch` or `getche`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **read the text while it is typed** by the user, you'll have to attach to the "key up/down" or "text changed" events (depending on your ulterior motives).